# How to install Ubuntu touch on windows tablet?

Tags: system-installation, ubuntu-touch, tablet

I want to install Ubuntu Touch on my Acer tab but I don't have idea how to install it on tablet.

How to install Ubuntu Touch to Acer Iconia W4-82164GB with specs:

- Screen Size: 8
- Internal Storage: 64GB, 2GB RAM
- OS: Windows 8.1
- Processor: Intel Atom Z3740
- Speed: 1.33 GHz Quad core

?

Answer (score 1):

Supported devices: https://devices.ubuntu-touch.io/
The installer: https://ubuntu-touch.io/get-ut